# Is there a way to check if the Info Panel is currently toggled in AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: swift, tvos

How can I specifically check that Info Panel (with audio settings etc.) is toggled during video playback? The only way I found so far is checking on `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate` method `willTransitionToVisibilityOfTransportBar` , however in the method I was not able to distinguish between transport bar and info panel toggled/disappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have only found the way how to disable the info screen by `self.playbackControlsIncludeInfoViews = false`